# handle event when pushwoosh received message in the background

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-event, pushwoosh

I've implemented pushwoosh in my android app and would like to perform some task when the pushwoosh is received while in the background.

The way I see it - pushwoosh only lets me perform code once the user clicked the notification. How can I perform something once pushwoosh receiver gets the notification in the bg?

Comment: looking for the sollution ?